# Put forms next to each other

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

Working on a project where I am going to put forms next to each other. But having the problem that they are not next to eachother. I am going to have 20 rows with input forms and the label name of the forms can be long so very unsure how to handle that.

This is how far I am right now: http://www.bootply.com/129498

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are floating properly next to each other, but your second column has a div an id of "dato", which is throwing off the positioning a bit. You have a couple options:

Adding:

```
#dato {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

will cause your second column to flow correctly.